# How to embed php in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a do_shortcut and I need to embed it in a twig template. I tried by coping the code in a php file my-code.php:

```
<?php do_shortcut('[my-code]'); ?>
```

Next, in the twig page over.twig:

```
   {{ include ('options/my-code.php') }}

/* I also tried */

   {% php %}
            <?php do_shortcut('[my-code]'); ?>
   {% endphp %}
```

But doesn't work. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You can't do that, you should create a twig extension and transform the php function into a twig function: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 2):

About the `include` part, create a `my_code.html.twig` file at app/Resources/views/my_code.html.twig and copy-paste your code from `my-code.php`

Then you can include that code anywhere like :

```
{% include 'my_code.html.twig' %}
```

EDIT: tested and working in symfony3

Answer (score -9):

Try this code:

```
{{ wp.do_shortcode('[shortcode]')|raw }}
```