# is there any possibility to including twig file into php files

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

i'm developing in php and i'm using twig for templates, 
i have one file

```
footer.html.twig
```

in all my files with twig extension

i'm using

```
 {% include 'footer.html.twig' %}
```

and one page i made in php

```
 myPage.php
```

is there any possibility to include `footer.html.twig` into `myPage.php`

Comment: Instantiate a `TwigEnvironment`, `render` the template and `echo` it...!?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296850/how-to-embed-php-in-twig